# Can't Parse String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

I have the following string that I would like to split on the `\xA7` character.

`\xFF$New Server\xA77\xA750`

The problem being is that I can't figure out how to tell Ruby to split it correctly on the `\xA7` marker.

This is the error I get:

```
>> "\xFF$New Server\xA77\xA750".split("\xA7")
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
from (irb):26:in `split'
from (irb):26
from /Users/wedtm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When forcing the encoding to `BINARY` you can work around that issue, though not sure if it's the correct solution or breaks other things...

```
input = "\xFF$New Server\xA77\xA750".force_encoding('BINARY')
split = "\xA7".force_encoding('BINARY')
input.split(split) # => ["\xFF$New Server", "7", "50"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the string has an invalid utf-8 byte sequence. If you don't care about that try putting this at the top of your document:

```
# coding: ascii
```